# Postfix repeatedly sending same message twice a day

Tags: postfix, email

I have postfix, which I use on server just for sending emails. It's not used for incoming emails. It works flawlessly, howevere one email is stucked SOMEWHERE and postfix keeps sending it all over again. Usually twice a day, but not at fixed times but randomly.

I've checked the postfix queue by using

```
postqueue -p
```

And I have deleted the queue by using

```
postsuper -d ALL
```

The message wasn't in the queue and I have no idea where it is coming from. All other emails are sent correctly.

Can anybody help me with any advice what to check or where to find this specific email and where is it coming from ?

Edit: log from /var/log/mail.log

```
Mar 17 19:48:16 server postfix/smtpd[17347]: warning: dict_nis_init: NIS domain name not set - NIS lookups disabled
Mar 17 19:48:16 server postfix/smtpd[17347]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Mar 17 19:48:16 server postfix/smtpd[17347]: E98FE3BC16A: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
Mar 17 19:48:16 server postfix/cleanup[17351]: E98FE3BC16A: message-id=<528eb6e8fe4787efd4eec72e4d09c4ee@domain.com>
Mar 17 19:48:17 server postfix/qmgr[1274]: E98FE3BC16A: from=<info@domain.com>, size=3663, nrcpt=2 (queue active)
Mar 17 19:48:17 server postfix/smtpd[17347]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Mar 17 19:48:18 server postfix/smtp[17353]: E98FE3BC16A: to=<info@domain.com>, relay=aspmx.l.google.com[74.125.39.27]:25, delay=2, delays=0.06/0.01/0.07/1.8, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1300387694 s27si2779751faa.12)
Mar 17 19:48:19 server postfix/smtp[17352]: E98FE3BC16A: to=<user@domain2.com>, relay=mx50.seznam.cz[77.75.73.47]:25, delay=2.9, delays=0.06/0/2/0.84, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Mail 12213 queued for delivery in session 3e4e00000063.)
Mar 17 19:48:19 server postfix/qmgr[1274]: E98FE3BC16A: removed
```

Comment: What does the mail log say? (it's probably in /var/log/mail.log or similar)

Comment: Can You post more about the email ? ( sender, to and message) or post the email too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry, but under more investigation into this problem, it really wasn't fault of postfix. User unknowingly kept requesting page that sent this email every once in a while. So this is a explanation to my question.

Comment: Cool - glad you got to the bottom of it.

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't look stuck to me - a process on your server is connecting to Postfix and sending an email, Postfix is successfully relaying the email to it's two recipients. What I'd say you need to do is figure out what's generating the email.

Is there anything in the email that might give you a clue as to which process is sending it?

If there's nothing in the emails being sent, is it worth ruling out the NIS domain warning as having something to do with this? Look for something like "alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases, nis:mail.aliases" and remove any reference to NIS (take a copy of any config files you change first, though).